# Can I replace the value of the <see cref=""> documentation tag?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, xml-documentation

Is it possible to change the displayed string when using the  tag in c#? I'd like to do something like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Do some magic on the <see cref="String">provided text</see>.
/// </summary>
public void SomeMethod(String param)
{
    // Whatever
}
```

So that a developer sees

> Do some magic on the `provided text`

but will be able to be redirected to the `String` class when clicking on it.

Here is an image displaying my issue:

[image]

Comment: [The documentation says no](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/see), but I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

Comment: [Exactly what you tried supposedly used to work, but no more.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48617/how-does-one-pluralize-see-cref-notations)

Comment: I looked around and didn't find an answer. I think this would be a big improvement on how we write documentation in .NET. If anyone know how we can suggest this feature, let me know!

Comment: This can be proposed here: https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/tree/master/proposals

Comment: I [created a proposal](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1781) and there is similar functionality being proposed [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1764).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so currently this is not possible, as is it not described in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/see) but this feature *was* [supported in the past](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/48617/how-does-one-pluralize-see-cref-notations).

I created a proposal over at the [C# Language Design repository over at GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1781) and a proposal for similar functionality can be found [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/1764). Hopefully this will be supported in the future!